# What is the point of a text qualifier, if it too can appear in the data? (more inside)

Tags: ssis

I have read that the delimiter is designed to separate two values in the data file, and that the text qualifier is designed to accomodate scenarios when the delimiter is in the actual data.  But what if the text qualifier could potentially be in the data too?

---

**Example:** pipe delimited data, with " as the text qualifier:

"ABC"|"DEF"|"GHI"

Now what if the text qualifier is inside the data:

"ABC"|"DE"F"|"GHI"

Now we're back to square one: we added a text qualifier because our delimiter could be inside the data, but now have the same problem with the text qualifier.

---

**2 questions:**

**1)** What is the point of using a text qualifier if its use is easily broken, just as with the delimiter?

**2)** It seems to me that the only reliable way to delimit data is to use a delimiter with multiple characters (example: |~| ) and pray that those characters are never in the data.  Is this correct?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your questions could be answered together:

The purpose of using `Text Qualifier` is to escape inline characters that are the same as the `Column Delimiter`, for example, in your case, you are using the pipe delimiter (Vertical delimiter), so `Text Qualifier` is introduced if there is some pipe characters in your text.  It will bring you a parsing issue if the inline symbol is the same as the qualifier, otherwise, you are using the different qualifier compared to the character you would like to escape.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if the text delimiter is as easy "broken" as the delimiter (both can appear in the data), then what is the value in using a text delimiter?  See what I mean?  It just doesn't feel like a solution at all, unless the source data intentionally filters out the text qualifier for every extract file.  And if the double-quote character is removed, that would damage a lot of data.  Example: if someone's sentence is quoting a famous person, and the quotes are removed.  See what I mean?  I just don't see how a text qualifier is going to solve the problem.

Comment: @user7560542, I got you, in most cases I have experienced, I need `Text Qualifier` when parsing the user comments, and I was using `Comma Delimiter`, so the inline `,` would be escaped by `Text Qualifier "(double quotation)`. Back to yours, I think you need to analysis the data first before using the correct configuration, and either the qualifier or delimiter could be any symbol only if it can parse correctly